# Python: Way to speed up a repeatedly executed eval statement?

Tags: python, eval

In my code, I'm using `eval` to evaluate a string expression given by the user.  Is there a way to compile or otherwise speed up this statement?

```
import math
import random

result_count = 100000
expression = "math.sin(v['x']) * v['y']"

variable = dict()
variable['x'] = [random.random() for _ in xrange(result_count)]
variable['y'] = [random.random() for _ in xrange(result_count)]

# optimize anything below this line

result = [0] * result_count

print 'Evaluating %d instances of the given expression:' % result_count
print expression

v = dict()
for index in xrange(result_count):
    for name in variable.keys():
        v[name] = variable[name][index]
    result[index] = eval(expression) # <-- option ONE
    #result[index] = math.sin(v['x']) * v['y'] # <-- option TWO
```

For a quick comparison option ONE takes 2.019 seconds on my machine, while option TWO takes only 0.218 seconds.  Surely Python has a way of doing this without hard-coding the expression.

Comment: Check out some alternatives to eval in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940 as well as some good reasons to stay away from it.

Comment: what if the user types `import os;os.system("rm -rf /")`? You need to write a parser to interpret the input string, and only recognise what you expect: `sin`, `cos`, `log`, etc. Throw an error if what they enter doesn't work. It could be bad if you don't do that.

Comment: If the user wants to "rm -rf /" or ":(){ :|: & };:" he can do it in a shell instead of within Python.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can also trick python:

```
expression = "math.sin(v['x']) * v['y']"
exp_as_func = eval('lambda: ' + expression)
```

And then use it like so:

```
exp_as_func()
```

Speed test:

```
In [17]: %timeit eval(expression)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.8 us per loop

In [18]: %timeit exp_as_func()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 541 ns per loop
```

---

As a side note, if `v` is not a global, you can create the lambda like this:

```
exp_as_func = eval('lambda v: ' + expression)
```

and call it:

```
exp_as_func(my_v)
```

Comment: This is a noticeable speed improvement over F.J.'s response, which was already a big speed improvement.

Comment: I guess this trick is equivalent to use `compile` before eval because when you run it you get `The slowest run took 17.90 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached`.

Comment: Who is "F. J."?

Answer (score 22):

You can avoid the overhead by compiling the expression in advance using [`compiler.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/compiler.html) for Python 2 or [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=compile#compile) for Python 3 :

```
In [1]: import math, compiler

In [2]: v = {'x': 2, 'y': 4}

In [3]: expression = "math.sin(v['x']) * v['y']"

In [4]: %timeit eval(expression)
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.5 us per loop

In [5]: compiled = compiler.compile(expression, '<string>', 'eval')

In [6]: %timeit eval(compiled)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 823 ns per loop
```

Just make sure you do the compiling only once (outside of the loop).  As mentioned in comments, when using `eval` on user submitted strings make sure you are very careful about what you accept.

Comment: compiler.compile is compile in python3

Answer (score 4):

I think you are optimising the wrong end. If you want to perform the same operation for a lot of numbers you should consider using numpy:

```
import numpy
import time
import math
import random

result_count = 100000
expression = "sin(x) * y"

namespace = dict(
    x=numpy.array(
        [random.random() for _ in xrange(result_count)]),
    y=numpy.array(
        [random.random() for _ in xrange(result_count)]),
    sin=numpy.sin,
)
print ('Evaluating %d instances '
       'of the given expression:') % result_count
print expression

start = time.time()
result = eval(expression, namespace)
numpy_time = time.time() - start
print "With numpy:", numpy_time


assert len(result) == result_count
assert all(math.sin(a) * b == c for a, b, c in
           zip(namespace["x"], namespace["y"], result))
```

To give you an idea about the possible gain I've added a variant using generic python and the lambda trick:

```
from math import sin
from itertools import izip

start = time.time()
f = eval("lambda: " + expression)
result = [f() for x, y in izip(namespace["x"], namespace["y"])]
generic_time = time.time() - start
print "Generic python:", generic_time
print "Ratio:", (generic_time / numpy_time)
```

Here are the results on my aging machine:

```
$ python speedup_eval.py 
Evaluating 100000 instances of the given expression:
sin(x) * y
With numpy: 0.006098985672
Generic python: 0.270224094391
Ratio: 44.3063992807
```

The speed-up is not as high as I expected, but still significant.

Comment: I don't have access to `numpy` here.  But I agree, it might speed things up.  I'm generally against relying on a third party library if I can get by without it.