# Parsing code used in loop only once

Tags: python, parsing, loops

I'm writing a code in Python which can be used to solve equations. The user must first input a code via a raw_input(), which will then be used to calculate y for every x in a loop with eval(), like so:

```
#some imports (math) and other irrelevant code
Code = raw_input('please enter your equation')
Low = raw_input('please enter the lowest number in the domain')
High = raw_input('please enter the highest number in the domain')
X = Low
While X <= High:
    Y = eval(code)
    #complicated code to solve equation
    X += #number depending on the amount of decimals
#simpler code to print the result
```

The problem is that parsing the input code using eval() for every loop is extremely slow. Is there a way to parse the code only once and then use it as a function in the rest of the program?

Comment: Move it outside of the loop?

Comment: If "code" does not reference any variables/data that changes in the loop then you can just move that line to be above the while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile the expression in advance using [`compiler.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#compiler.compile) ([deprecated](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-January/011693.html) since Python v2.6).

With Python 3.x:

- the [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) functionality is built-in
- the [AST module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html) offers similar functions

Also take a look at: [Python: Way to speed up a repeatedly executed eval statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12467570/3235496)

EDIT

Some examples:

```
>>> expr = 'x*x + 2*x + 1'
>>> expr_obj = compile(expr, '', 'eval')
>>> x = 1
>>> y = eval(expr)
```

and now

```
>>> y
4
>>> x = 2
>>> y = eval(expr)
>>> y
9
```

`compile` is a lower level version of `eval` (and `exec`). It doesn't evaluate/execute your expression/statement but returns a code object that can do it.

---

PS as a general rule when using `eval` on user submitted strings you must be very careful about what you accept (it's a potential security hole).

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but compile(code) returns the location of the code instead of the evaluation.

Comment: `compile` doesn't evaluate your expression but returns a code object that can do it. I've added an example.

Comment: Thank you, that reduced calculation times significantly!

Comment: To give you an example: it can now calculate all 128 intersections of tan(x**2)=y with the x-axis in just 3300 miliseconds accurate to 7 decimals on my 1.4Ghz iPad.

Answer (score 1):

if the equation in code doen't need any reference to X, then you could move `Y = eval(code)` outside the loop. Otherwise you need it at this position to access X and its current value.

Comment: If the equation doesn't reference X, then the value of Y would be constant, and there would be no need for the loop in the first place. It looks like the OP is trying to get a table of values of Y for different values of X, implying that Y *is* a function of X.

Answer (score 0):

If the user inputs the equation in terms of a single variable "X", then you can convert it to a function using Python's `lambda` keyword:

```
CodeAsFunction = eval('lambda X : ' + Code)
```

(For this to work, the user just enters the right-hand side of the equation, `3*X + 100`, not `Y = 3*X+100`.)

Then in the body of your loop, you can call this function instead:

```
while X = High:
    Y = CodeAsFunction(X)
    ... etc. ...
```

Note, `eval` is now only being called once, to create the callable `CodeAsFunction` variable.

Of course, you must take care regarding security issues, as have already been mentioned by other posters.