# Speed up Python eval when reading and evaluating list of equations from file

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have put together a simple Python script which reads a large list of algebraic expressions from a text file on separate lines, evaluates the mathematics on each line and puts it into a numpy array. The eigenvalues of this matrix are then found. The parameters A,B,C will then be changed and the program run again, hence a function is used to achieve this.

Some of these text files will have millions of lines of equations, so after profiling the code I found that the `eval` command accounts for approximately 99% of the execution time. I am aware of the dangers of using `eval` but this code will only ever be used by myself. All other parts of the code are fast, except the call to `eval`.

Here is the code where `mat_size` is set to 500 which represents a  500*500 array meaning 250,000 lines of equations are being read in from the file. I cannot provide the file as it is ~ 0.5GB in size, but have provided an example of what it looks like below and it only uses basic mathematical operations.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from scipy.linalg import eigvalsh

mat_size = 500

# Read the file line by line
with open("test_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 

# Function to evaluate the maths and build the numpy array
def my_func(A,B,C):
    lst = []
    for i in lines:   
        # Strip the \n
        new = eval(i.rstrip())
        lst.append(new)
    # Build the numpy array
    AA = np.array(lst,dtype=np.float64)
    # Resize it to mat_size
    matt = np.resize(AA,(mat_size,mat_size))
    return matt 

# Function to find eigenvalues of matrix
def optimise(x):
    A,B,C = x
    test = my_func(A,B,C)
    ev=-1*eigvalsh(test)
    return ev[-(1)]   

# Define what A,B,C are, this can be changed each time the program is run
x0 = [7.65,5.38,4.00]

# Print result
print(optimise(x0))
```

A few lines of an example input text file: (`mat_size` can be changed to 2 to run this file)

```
.5/A**3*B**5+C
35.5/A**3*B**5+3*C
.8/C**3*A**5+C**9
.5/A*3+B**5-C/45
```

I am aware `eval` is usually bad practice and slow, so I looked for other means to achieving a speed up. I tried methods outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467570/python-way-to-speed-up-a-repeatedly-executed-eval-statement) but none of these appeared to work. I also tried applying sympy to the problem but that caused a massive slowdown. What is a better way of going about this problem?

***EDIT***

From the suggestion to use `numexpr` instead, I have come across an issue where it grinds to a halt compared to the standard `eval`. For some instances the matrix elements contain quite a lot of algebraic expressions. Here is an example of just one matrix element, i.e one of the equations in the file (it contains a few more terms not defined in the code above, but can be easily defined at top of the code):

```
-71*A**3/(A+B)**7-61*B**3/(A+B)**7-3/2/B**2/C**2*A**6/(A+B)**7-7/4/B**3/m3*A**6/(A+B)**7-49/4/B**2/C*A**6/(A+B)**7+363/C*A**3/(A+B)**7*z3+451*B**3/C/(A+B)**7*z3-3/2*B**5/C/A**2/(A+B)**7-3/4*B**7/C/A**3/(A+B)**7-1/B/C**3*A**6/(A+B)**7-3/2/B**2/C*A**5/(A+B)**7-107/2/C/m3*A**4/(A+B)**7-21/2/B/C*A**4/(A+B)**7-25/2*B/C*A**2/(A+B)**7-153/2*B**2/C*A/(A+B)**7-5/2*B**4/C/m3/(A+B)**7-B**6/C**3/A/(A+B)**7-21/2*B**4/C/A/(A+B)**7-7/4/B**3/C*A**7/(A+B)**7+86/C**2*A**4/(A+B)**7*z3+90*B**4/C**2/(A+B)**7*z3-1/4*B**6/m3/A**3/(A+B)**7-149/4/B/C*A**5/(A+B)**7-65*B**2/C**3*A**4/(A+B)**7-241/2*B/C**2*A**4/(A+B)**7-38*B**3/C**3*A**3/(A+B)**7+19*B**2/C**2*A**3/(A+B)**7-181*B/C*A**3/(A+B)**7-47*B**4/C**3*A**2/(A+B)**7+19*B**3/C**2*A**2/(A+B)**7+362*B**2/C*A**2/(A+B)**7-43*B**5/C**3*A/(A+B)**7-241/2*B**4/C**2*A/(A+B)**7-272*B**3/C*A/(A+B)**7-25/4*B**6/C**2/A/(A+B)**7-77/4*B**5/C/A/(A+B)**7-3/4*B**7/C**2/A**2/(A+B)**7-23/4*B**6/C/A**2/(A+B)**7-11/B/C**2*A**5/(A+B)**7-13/B**2/m3*A**5/(A+B)**7-25*B/C**3*A**4/(A+B)**7-169/4/B/m3*A**4/(A+B)**7-27*B**2/C**3*A**3/(A+B)**7-47*B/C**2*A**3/(A+B)**7-27*B**3/C**3*A**2/(A+B)**7-38*B**2/C**2*A**2/(A+B)**7-131/4*B/m3*A**2/(A+B)**7-25*B**4/C**3*A/(A+B)**7-65*B**3/C**2*A/(A+B)**7-303/4*B**2/m3*A/(A+B)**7-5*B**5/C**2/A/(A+B)**7-49/4*B**4/m3/A/(A+B)**7-1/2*B**6/C**2/A**2/(A+B)**7-5/2*B**5/m3/A**2/(A+B)**7-1/2/B/C**3*A**7/(A+B)**7-3/4/B**2/C**2*A**7/(A+B)**7-25/4/B/C**2*A**6/(A+B)**7-45*B/C**3*A**5/(A+B)**7-3/2*B**7/C**3/A/(A+B)**7-123/2/C*A**4/(A+B)**7-37/B*A**4/(A+B)**7-53/2*B*A**2/(A+B)**7-75/2*B**2*A/(A+B)**7-11*B**6/C**3/(A+B)**7-39/2*B**5/C**2/(A+B)**7-53/2*B**4/C/(A+B)**7-7*B**4/A/(A+B)**7-7/4*B**5/A**2/(A+B)**7-1/4*B**6/A**3/(A+B)**7-11/C**3*A**5/(A+B)**7-43/C**2*A**4/(A+B)**7-363/4/m3*A**3/(A+B)**7-11*B**5/C**3/(A+B)**7-45*B**4/C**2/(A+B)**7-451/4*B**3/m3/(A+B)**7-5/C**3*A**6/(A+B)**7-39/2/C**2*A**5/(A+B)**7-49/4/B**2*A**5/(A+B)**7-7/4/B**3*A**6/(A+B)**7-79/2/C*A**3/(A+B)**7-207/2*B**3/C/(A+B)**7+22/B/C**2*A**5/(A+B)**7*z3+94*B/C**2*A**3/(A+B)**7*z3+76*B**2/C**2*A**2/(A+B)**7*z3+130*B**3/C**2*A/(A+B)**7*z3+10*B**5/C**2/A/(A+B)**7*z3+B**6/C**2/A**2/(A+B)**7*z3+3/B**2/C**2*A**6/(A+B)**7*z3+7/B**3/C*A**6/(A+B)**7*z3+52/B**2/C*A**5/(A+B)**7*z3+169/B/C*A**4/(A+B)**7*z3+131*B/C*A**2/(A+B)**7*z3+303*B**2/C*A/(A+B)**7*z3+49*B**4/C/A/(A+B)**7*z3+10*B**5/C/A**2/(A+B)**7*z3+B**6/C/A**3/(A+B)**7*z3-3/4*B**7/C/m3/A**3/(A+B)**7-7/4/B**3/C/m3*A**7/(A+B)**7-49/4/B**2/C/m3*A**6/(A+B)**7-149/4/B/C/m3*A**5/(A+B)**7-293*B/C/m3*A**3/(A+B)**7+778*B**2/C/m3*A**2/(A+B)**7-480*B**3/C/m3*A/(A+B)**7-77/4*B**5/C/m3/A/(A+B)**7-23/4*B**6/C/m3/A**2/(A+B)**7
```

`numexpr` completely chokes when the matrix elements are of this form, whereas `eval` evaluates it instantaneously. For just a 10*10 matrix (100 equations in file) `numexpr` takes about 78 seconds to process the file, whereas `eval` takes 0.01 seconds. Profiling the code that uses `numexpr` reveals that the `getExprnames` and `precompile` function of numexpr are the causes of the issue with `precompile` taking 73.5 seconds of the total time and `getExprNames` taking 3.5 seconds of the time. Why would the precompile cause such a bottleneck in this particular calculation along with the getExprNames? Is this module just not well suited to long algebraic expressions?

Comment: I'd use `numexpr.evaluate()` - which is safe, very fast and supports numpy arrays...

Comment: @MaxU See edit for an interesting behaviour of numexpr vs eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to speed eval() up in this particular instance by making use of the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) library. I read the file in as usual, but then break the list into equal sized sub-lists which can then be processed separately on different CPU's and the evaluated sub-lists recombined at the end. This offers a nice speedup over the original method. I am sure the code below can be simplified/optimised; but for now it works (for instance what if there is a prime number of list elements? this will mean unequal lists). Some rough benchmarks show it is ~ 3 times faster using the 4 CPU's of my laptop. Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

with open("test.txt", 'r') as h:
    linesHH = h.readlines()


# Get the number of list elements
size = len(linesHH)

# Break apart the list into the desired number of chunks
chunk_size = size/4
chunks = [linesHH[x:x+chunk_size] for x in xrange(0, len(linesHH), chunk_size)]

# Declare variables
A = 0.1
B = 2
C = 2.1
m3 = 1
z3 = 2

# Declare all the functions that process the substrings
def my_funcHH1(A,B,C,que):   #add a argument to function for assigning a queue to each chunk function
    lstHH1 = []
    for i in chunks[0]:
        HH1 = eval(i)
        lstHH1.append(HH1)
    que.put(lstHH1)

def my_funcHH2(A,B,C,que):    
    lstHH2 = []
    for i in chunks[1]:
        HH2 = eval(i)
        lstHH2.append(HH2)
    que.put(lstHH2)

def my_funcHH3(A,B,C,que):    
    lstHH3 = []
    for i in chunks[2]:
        HH3 = eval(i)
        lstHH3.append(HH3)
    que.put(lstHH3)

def my_funcHH4(A,B,C,que):    
    lstHH4 = []
    for i in chunks[3]:
        HH4 = eval(i)
        lstHH4.append(HH4)
    que.put(lstHH4)

queue1 = Queue()    
queue2 = Queue()  
queue3 = Queue()  
queue4 = Queue()  

# Declare the processes
p1 = Process(target= my_funcHH1, args= (A,B,C,queue1))    
p2 = Process(target= my_funcHH2, args= (A,B,C,queue2))
p3 = Process(target= my_funcHH3, args= (A,B,C,queue3))
p4 = Process(target= my_funcHH4, args= (A,B,C,queue4))

# Start them
p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()

HH1 = queue1.get()
HH2 = queue2.get()
HH3 = queue3.get()
HH4 = queue4.get()
p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()

# Obtain the final result by combining lists together again.
mergedlist = HH1 + HH2 + HH3 + HH4
```