# python eval speed and performance

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary
let say

```
prices={
    "set1": {
        "price1": 200,
        "price2": 300
         ....
    },
    "set2": {
        "price1": 200,
        "price2": 300,
        ....

    }
}
```

I have a set of rules.
let say

```
rules={
    "set1": {
        "a>0 and b<10 and price1>300": 1.5,
        "a+b=10 or c>20": 2.5
         ....
    },
    "set2": {
        "a=c and b!=d or price2<100": 3.5,
        "a=b and price2 in range(100,300)": 4,
        ....

    }
}
```

Here a,b,c,d.. are variables defined with some values
if any of the rules in the corresponding set satisfies then it will be added to prices in `prices`.

Right now I am using 
`if eval(rule)` in for loops
but total around near 20000 loops are there so taking at least 5 minutes to execute.

Is there any option to make it faster?

I am using Django framework for this api

Edit:
when I use lambda
it is showing an error as variable not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Way to speed up a repeatedly executed eval statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467570/python-way-to-speed-up-a-repeatedly-executed-eval-statement)

Comment: if i use lambda i am getting error a b c etc not defined

Comment: Check the "sidenote": `eval('lambda v: ' + expression)`, try replacing `v` with `a, b, c`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use lambdas or functions for this type of process.  To do so, you would need to ensure that the variables used in the lambdas or functions are in scope of the declaration of your rules dictionary. But perhaps this may prove difficult if your code and rule declarations are not contained within a single function.

You have not posted enough contextual information/code for us to determine where your approach is failing, but perhaps an example will put you on the right track:

```
prices={
    "set1": {
        "price1": 200,
        "price2": 300
    },
    "set2": {
        "price1": 200,
        "price2": 250
    }
}

def Rule(expression,priceValue):
    return (compile(expression,"<string>","eval"),priceValue)

rules={
    "set1": [
        Rule("a>0 and b<10 and price1>300",1.5),
        Rule("a+b==10 or c>20",2.5)
    ],
    "set2": [
        Rule("a==c and b!=d or price2<100",3.5),
        Rule("a==b and price2 in range(100,300)",4)
    ]
}

context = { "a":5, "b":5, "c":5, "d":0 }
for setId,priceSet in prices.items():
    price = []
    for rule,value in rules[setId]:
        context.update(priceSet)
        if eval(rule,globals(),context):
            price.append(value)
    print(setId,price,sum(price))

# set1 [2.5] 2.5
# set2 [3.5, 4] 7.5
```

- To make repeated eval() function calls faster, you can use compile()
  to obtain a "compiled" version of your string formula.  This is what
  you should store in your rules dictionary.
- The content of a rule set only needs to be an array of tuples.  This
  will make using the rules list a bit easier.
- In your sample rule expressions, you are using a single equal sign
  (=) for testing equality, Python needs a double equal sign otherwise
  the formulas will not produce the expected results.

I am not sure what you meant by *"it will add to prices in prices"*.  Since your rules are already using price1 and price2 in their expressions, they seem to need the content of the prices dictionary (or at least one of its sets) to produce an answer.  Why (and how) then would they update the very data structure that they rely upon to respond ? and with what keys ?.  I could not produce an example that meets that requirement.  Hopefully you will be able to adapt my example to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but i cannot edit rules and prices its coming from excel sheet